# How to identify latent factors on only one observed variable

Tags: multiple-regression, factor-analysis, latent-variable, multivariate-regression

Is there an approach to identify latent factors impacting the outcome of only one observed variable?

I have a number of observations for one variable and assume that it is affected by two latent factors. Below you find an example. data_1 consist of the observations for the first latent factor and data_2 consists of observations for the second latent factor.

Unfortunately my experimental design does not allow to easily distinguish between both latent factors. What I actually observe is something like the combination of data_1 and data_2. This is what I called "data" in the code below.

Figure 1: So what I observe is something like this:
[image: actual observation]

Figure 2: Is there a possibility to identify the underlying latent factors that possibly affect my observations, so that I get something like this?
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

#DATA---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#set seed-----------------------------------------------------------------------
set.seed(789)

#sample data set----------------------------------------------------------------
data_1 <- mvrnorm(n = 100,                                                     
                  mu = c(0, 0),                                                
                  Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.8,                               
                                 0.8, 1),                                 
                                 nrow = 2, ncol = 2))       

data_2 <- mvrnorm(n = 100,                                                    
                  mu = c(0, 0),                                              
                  Sigma = matrix(c(1,0.9,
                                   0.9,1),
                                 nrow = 2, ncol = 2)) 

#...combine 2 data sets---------------------------------------------------------
data_1 <- as.data.frame(data_1)
colnames(data_1) <- c("x", "y")
data_1$factor <- "factor_1"

data_2 <- as.data.frame(data_2)
colnames(data_2) <- c("x", "y")
data_2$factor <- "factor_2"

data <- bind_rows(data_1, data_2)

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +                             
  geom_point()
```

EDIT:
data_1 and data_2 represent two data sets. These are two observations of the Variables X and Y. My question: Is there a possibility to disentangle the combined data set of above (figure 1) so that I can get the two regression lines in the second figure.
I imagine that the data points belong to two different groups. If life would be easy, I would see them separately like in this figures:

Figure 3: Data 1
[image]

Figure 4: Data 2
[image]

However, I only see them as in Figure 1. Is there a possibility to identify the different groups with the different slopes?

Comment: Could you explain your setup in words and equations instead of code? It seems to me that data_1 is 2D gaussian with covariance $\Sigma_1$ and data_2 is also 2D gaussian with covariance $\Sigma_2$. If I understand correctly, bind_rows concatenates the two datasets, giving you a mixture of 2D gaussians.

Comment: You want to disentangle the two distributions and estimate the parameters $\mu_1, \mu_2, \Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ from the raw data ?

Comment: Looking at the first plot, in an eyeball judgement, I think that you should also consider the possibility of an approximately linear relationship between 'x' and 'y'.

Comment: What are X and Y in your graph?

Comment: Hello @ArnoY, you are right. My Explanations were rather missleading (sorry!). These are rather two normal distributed variables. What you propose sounds like the result I am searching for. Basically what I want is to disentangle both so that I get two regression lines.

Comment: @RichardHardy excuse me, these should be actually two randomly distributed variables.

Comment: @Ertxiem-reinstateMonica right. But in principle it should be also possible that they are for example negatively correlated.

Comment: How are X and Y related to your problem? Is X = data_1 and Y = data_2?

Comment: @RichardHardy data_1 and data_2 are different observations of the variables x and y.

I will add this in the description of the original post! Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the R code is describing a Gaussian mixture distribution $X$ with two mixture components ("latent factors") $G_1\sim N(0, 1)$ and $G_2\sim N(0, 1)$ such that

$f(x) = 0.5g_1(x) + 0.5g_2(x)$ and

the correlations $\rho_{g_1y}= 0.8$ and $\rho_{g_2y}= 0.9$.

The goal is to disentangle the mixture components within $X$ so that separate linear regressions can be run for each component. If the problem is defined correctly, then there are several methods used for mixture decomposition. My first thought was K-means clustering which might be sufficient if the distance between the latent random variables were sufficiently large. A common method used is model-based clustering using Gaussian mixture models estimated by Expectation–Maximization algorithm (the library `mclust` in R).

However, in the example provided, the mixture components are defined so similarly that their combination in $X$ leads to significant information loss -- I don't know if there is a method that would be quite satisfactory at disentangling them. But perhaps mixture modelling methods may still be of use to you if it is possible for the latent factors to exhibit more distinguishing properties.

Here is an example of EM algorithm using `mclust` where $\rho_{g_1y}= 0.8$ and $\rho_{g_2y}= -0.8$. The method is successful, except at the overlapping cluster centers ($\mu_{g_1}=\mu_{g_2}=0$) where it unsurprisingly struggles. With the resulting classifications, you can then disentangle the `data` into two datasets and run regressions on each.
[image: EM algorithm]

```
#DATA---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#set seed-----------------------------------------------------------------------
set.seed(789)

#sample data set----------------------------------------------------------------
data_1 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000,                                                     
                  mu = c(0, 0),                                                
                  Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.8,                               
                                   0.8, 1),                                 
                                 nrow = 2, ncol = 2))       

data_2 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000,                                                    
                  mu = c(0, 0),                                              
                  Sigma = matrix(c(1,-0.8,
                                   -0.8,1),
                                 nrow = 2, ncol = 2)) 

#...combine 2 data sets---------------------------------------------------------
data_1 <- as.data.frame(data_1)
colnames(data_1) <- c("x", "y")
data_1$factor <- "2"

data_2 <- as.data.frame(data_2)
colnames(data_2) <- c("x", "y")
data_2$factor <- "1"

data <- bind_rows(data_1, data_2)

library(mclust)
EMCluster <- Mclust(data.frame(x=data$x, y=data$y), G = 2)
plot(EMCluster, what = "classification")
data$emcluster <- EMCluster$classification
```

Comment: this looks promising and I will try it. Thank you so much for the clear description of your way to solve my problem.

Comment: No problem. There are [other methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Parameter_estimation_and_system_identification) you could also research, but hopefully this nudges you to the right path.